# Uploading a file with custom generated symfony 1.4 forms

Tags: file-upload, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I use a module that creates customized html forms through template partails

I need to manage 4 file uploads of a form.

In actions I pull all field data like so:

```
$allData = $request->getParameterHolder()->getAll();
```

which would get me the uploaded file name, but I need to also save that file to the uploads dir.

I am trying to bind the form like so:

```
if( isset($customData['getAttachments']) && count($allData)){
        $attachments = $formInput->bind($request->getParameter('forms_input'), $request->getFiles('forms_input'));
}
```

which succesfully generates the `$attachments` object. Sanity check on that is a `var_dump($attachments);die;` which dumps:

```
object(FormsInput)#225 (18) { ["_node":protected]=> NULL ["_id":protected]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(5) "32171" } ["_data":protected]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(5) "32171" ["form_uid"]=> string(32) "aef79b2d47722ca154788cc9c8f8de2b" ["data_array"]=> string(770) "a:20:{s:9:...
```

How to I extract the file and push to a directory. I tried this:

```
$file = $attachments->getValue('file');
  if($file) {
  $filename = sha1($file->getOriginalName()).$file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
  $file->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$formTitle.'/'.$usrDir.''.$filename);
}
```

but it throws this error:

```
Unknown record property / related component "value" on "FormsInput"
```

How can I get the uploaded into a sf dir?

**UPDATE**

Tried to use the sfValidatorFile class, but I cannot figure out how to pass it the parameters from the $attachment object:

```
$file = new sfValidatorFile();
if($file) {
$filename = sha1($file->getOriginalName()).$file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
$file->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/uploadedDir');
}
```

throws this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method sfValidatorFile::save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you intended to do with the $file->save requires an *sfValidatedFile* object.
If FormsInput is an instance of *sfFormObject*, you can configure your form with 4 *sfValidatorFile* with the path you wanted in option. It will do the job you need.

Comment: I'm not using the sf forms in its traditional sense. In the FormsInputForms class, I am not defining widgets. I am using a partial  for the html, then serializing that form data. The $attachments has the file info, but I still do not know how to extract it from the $attachment object and send to a dir. See updated code above

Comment: If you're not using the forms functionality then save your files in the "traditional PHP way" (with `_FILES` and `move_uploaded_file()`). In fact - why do you use Symfony forms if you don't use widgets and validation. It's just doesn't make sense.

Comment: In many applications, we use the Symfony form functionality. This happens to be a specific instance where we need to use a different method.